# How to uninstall ruby-oci8

Tags: ruby, uninstallation, oracle-call-interface

The ruby gem that I am using require **ruby-oci8 version 2+.**
However it seems that my machine already have ruby-oci8 *version 1.0.0*. But this I can't uninstall.

I've run **gem uninstall ruby-oci8** succesfully.
Then, using irb type

```
require 'oci8'
=> true
OCI8::VERSION
=> "1.0.0"
```

How to clean up my Windows machine from ruby-oci v1.0.0 ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

http://ruby-oci8.rubyforge.org/en/FAQ_uninstall.html

Delete 3 files as mentioned in the link above